# How to create a black and white image of arbitrary size

Tags: image, scala, jvm

I want to create an arbitrary large image consisting solely of black and white pixel. I am currently using `BufferedImage`. This, however, hits a hard limit at 65500 Pixel.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1007)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:371)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:613)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1628)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1554)
```

How can I create an image of **arbitrary** size?

Bonus points: As the image is only black and white an efficient data format would be great.

Comment: According to the stack trace, you hit a limitation of the JPEG writer, not of `BufferedImage` nor ImageIO in general. When your image is “black and white”, i.e. not grayscale, either PNG or GIF, is a much more suitable output format.

Comment: does your solution have to be written in java?

Comment: @Liam I am using Scala, everything that can be used in Scala works for me. Thus, Java is an option as I can instantiate Java classes vis Scala.

Comment: I tried with a 700000 x 100 picture and sucessfully wrote a PNG, wrote a GIF w/o exception but truncated file, and got the same exception as you when writing as JPEG. I think, the solution is obvious.

Comment: @Holger than please post the solution code and claim the bounty ;)

Comment: Which dimensions do you need? I’d like to check them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html) might be the right image format for you, and it doesn't even require using Java's image libraries to work with.

```java
static void writeRandomBlackWhiteImage(
        OutputStream out, long width, long height) throws IOException {
    String header = String.format("P4\n%d\n%d\n", width, height);
    out.write(header.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

    // bytes = (width * height + 7) / 8, throwing ArithmeticException on overflow
    long bytes = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(width, height), 7L) / 8L;
    while (bytes > 0) {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) Math.min(0x4000, bytes)];
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(data);
        out.write(data);
        bytes -= data.size;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pbm")) {
        writeRandomBlackWhiteImage(out, 65536, 65536);
    }
}
```

Note that (unlike `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`) this can easily produce images with dimensions greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. (Although working with those images may be challenging.)

Comment: The challenge starts with having an actual image, rather than random data generated while writing.

Comment: @Holger Obviously, that could easily be replaced with whatever data source they have. This was just the easiest way to demonstrate that it can create arbitrary images of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 4):

You only hit a limitation of a specific image writer. When I tried with PNG, which is more suitable for truly black & white images anyway, larger images could be written and read back.

I used the following code for testing:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[][] sizes = {{4000, 4000 }, {40_000, 40_000 }, {70_000, 4000 }, {700_000, 400 }};
    for(int[] size: sizes) {
        int width = size[0], height = size[1];
        System.out.println("trying " + width + " x " + height);
        BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics2D gfx = bi.createGraphics();
        gfx.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gfx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        gfx.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gfx.drawOval(20, 20, width - 40 , height - 40);
        int off = Math.min(width, height) >>> 3;
        gfx.drawOval(off, off, width - off - off, height - off - off);
        gfx.dispose();

        test(bi, "PNG");
        test(bi, "GIF");
        test(bi, "JPEG");
    }
}
```

```java
static void test(BufferedImage bi, String format) throws IOException {
    Path f = Files.createTempFile("test", "-out."+format);
    try {
        try { ImageIO.write(bi, format, f.toFile()); }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            System.err.println(format+": "+t);
            return;
        }
        BufferedImage read;
        try { read = ImageIO.read(f.toFile()); }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            System.err.println(format+": written, re-reading: "+t);
            return;
        }
        if(bi.getWidth() != read.getWidth() || bi.getHeight() != read.getHeight()) {
            System.err.println(format+": size changed to "
                              +read.getWidth() + " x " + read.getHeight());
            return;
        }
        if(format.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
            // turn back to black & white, rounding away JPEG artifacts
            BufferedImage bw = new BufferedImage(
                read.getWidth(), read.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D gfx = bw.createGraphics();
            gfx.drawImage(read, 0, 0, null);
            gfx.dispose();
            read = bw;
        }
        for(int x = 0, w = bi.getWidth(); x < w; x++) {
            for(int y = 0, h = bi.getHeight(); y < h; y++) {
                if(bi.getRGB(x, y) != read.getRGB(x, y)) {
                    System.err.println(format+": content changed");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(format + ": sucessfully written and restored");
    }
    finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists(f);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
trying 4000 x 4000
PNG: sucessfully written and restored
GIF: sucessfully written and restored
JPEG: sucessfully written and restored
trying 40000 x 40000
PNG: sucessfully written and restored
GIF: sucessfully written and restored
JPEG: written, re-reading: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid scanline stride
trying 70000 x 4000
PNG: sucessfully written and restored
GIF: size changed to 4464 x 4000
JPEG: javax.imageio.IIOException: Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels
trying 700000 x 400
PNG: sucessfully written and restored
GIF: size changed to 44640 x 400
JPEG: javax.imageio.IIOException: Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels
```

I could not create `BufferedImage` object whose width × height exceeds the `int` value range, thought. This limitations seems to be hardcoded at several places of the implementation.